# DES_ENCRYPT with CodeIgniter ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

When I query my database with a query like this:

```
SELECT username, DES_DECRYPT(password) as password FROM accounts WHERE 1;
```

I will get my results like:

```
username | password
-------------------
testUser | pwtest
```

When I do the same in CodeIgniters Active Record like this:

```
$this->db->select("username, DES_DECRYPT(password) as password");
return $this->db->get("accounts")->result_array();
```

I will get the following array:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [username] => testUser
            [password] => 
        )
```

Any ideas why this isn't working or how to get this work?

Some additional info: the function will also be completely with an insert:

```
$this->db->insert("accounts", array("username" => "test", "password" => "DES_ENCRYPT(wachtwoord)"));
```

This will insert (in plain text) "DES_ENCRYPT(wachtwoord)"

PS. To prevent the standard "It's better to use a hash than save the password" discussion: I agree, but in this case is hashing not an option.

Answer (score 0):

codeigniter is not 100% complete and chances are its not using all of mysql functions. instead of writing it like this:

```
$this->db->select("username, DES_DECRYPT(password) as password");
```

write it like this:

```
$this->db->select("username, " . decrypt(password) . " as password");
```

where decrypt is the php equivalent of DES_DECRYPT. The php equivalent is Mcrypt more info found here:

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071201215913AAG8QKF

also avoid encrypting your password in such a way where it can be decrypted. its bad practice no one but the user should know their password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In some cases the application has to know credentials (for example to be able to connect with other services).